# Асинхронный таймер на тг боте Aiogram python

Tags: python, telegram, aiogram, asyncio, асинхронность

В общем задача создать бота, который выполняет определённые действия, если пользователь не ответит ему за определённый промежуток времени.

```
async def timer(chat_id, state: FSMContext):
    await asyncio.sleep(10)
    await any_func()
    

@dp.callback_query_handler()
async def callback_inline(call, state: FSMContext):
        await timer(call.chat.id, state: FSMContext)
```

Общий код упростил, но думаю суть понятна. Есть какие-нибудь варианты, не городя что-то с многопоточностью?

Comment: А если пользователь ответит за определённый промежуток времени? "не городя что-то с многопоточностью" у вас есть рабочий код с многопоточностью?

Comment: Я думаю что можно создать что-то типа листа с значениями `id` на `время последнего сообщения`, раз в какой-то промежуток прогоняться по нему и смотреть второе поле, если соответствует нашему условию по времени, сделать действия, удалить элемент